# apache access logs too many access entry

Tags: apache, access-log

I checked the access_log '/var/log/virtualmin/example.com_access_log'
and I found literally thousands of lines of the below (every second 15-20 request)

please guide me for this issue

access_log entry:

```
106.85.76.233 - - [22/Dec/2021:11:46:54 +0100] "GET /my-isp-provider/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5683 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1"
111.41.19.48 - - [22/Dec/2021:11:46:54 +0100] "GET /my-isp-provider/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5683 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1"
182.118.236.117 - - [22/Dec/2021:11:46:55 +0100] "GET /my-isp-provider/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5683 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1"
220.249.144.67 - - [22/Dec/2021:11:46:55 +0100] "GET /my-isp-provider/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5683 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1"
115.49.58.17 - - [22/Dec/2021:11:46:55 +0100] "GET /my-isp-provider/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5683 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1"
180.175.194.184 - - [22/Dec/2021:11:46:55 +0100] "GET /my-isp-provider/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5683 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1"
120.231.206.74 - - [22/Dec/2021:11:46:55 +0100] "GET /my-isp-provider/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5683 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1"
122.96.46.45 - - [22/Dec/2021:11:46:55 +0100] "GET /my-isp-provider/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5683 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1"
223.153.5.236 - - [22/Dec/2021:11:46:55 +0100] "GET /my-isp-provider/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5683 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1"
223.104.95.33 - - [22/Dec/2021:11:46:55 +0100] "GET /my-isp-provider/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5683 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1"
14.116.38.17 - - [22/Dec/2021:11:46:55 +0100] "GET /my-isp-provider/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5683 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1"
49.73.248.176 - - [22/Dec/2021:11:46:55 +0100] "GET /my-isp-provider/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5683 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1"
112.3.89.82 - - [22/Dec/2021:11:46:55 +0100] "GET /my-isp-provider/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5683 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1"
61.140.176.228 - - [22/Dec/2021:11:46:55 +0100] "GET /my-isp-provider/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5683 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1"
117.61.30.163 - - [22/Dec/2021:11:46:55 +0100] "GET /my-isp-provider/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5683 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1"
36.6.223.248 - - [22/Dec/2021:11:46:55 +0100] "GET /my-isp-provider/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5683 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1"
122.96.32.41 - - [22/Dec/2021:11:46:55 +0100] "GET /my-isp-provider/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5683 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1"
112.53.236.204 - - [22/Dec/2021:11:46:55 +0100] "GET /my-isp-provider/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5683 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1"
39.170.224.90 - - [22/Dec/2021:11:46:55 +0100] "GET /my-isp-provider/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5683 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1"
106.114.45.168 - - [22/Dec/2021:11:46:56 +0100] "GET /my-isp-provider/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5683 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1"
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not programming related, and as the operator of a webserver there's nothing you can do about unsolicited requests reaching your server (other than shielding it with one of the large providers who would filter them before they reach your server). Welcome to the internet. Everybody's server is constantly indexed, scanned, for potentially installed software, their version and possible vulnerabilities. There's nothing to see here.

Answer (score 0):

Usually "Go-http-client/1.1" (1) indicate the access from bot o crawlers.

Could be Google indexing your site, but since most of the IPs are from china and all of them are asking for the same URL, probably are bonet scans or a DoS attack.

1. https://user-agents.net/string/go-http-client-1-1